# Flutter dismissible background

Tags: flutter

I have a stateful widget who's root widget is a Dismissible.  When I pull down on the screen the dismissible reveals the background, which is black.  What I would like to see is the previous screen peeking out from behind.  I did come up with a hack that sort of works.  I stashed the previous stateful widget in a global variable, and set it as the background of the dismissible.  This is not a great solution and there are a number of issues that it causes, like some screen blinking.  Is there an official way to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried `pageView`?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, you an try to set some color with opacity like `Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5)` or even `Colors.transparent`

Comment: Page view isn't really the effect I am looking for.  This is the library we are using in native android https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr.  In the sample they slide from the side.  I did try transparent background but it did not work.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try push a `PageRouteBuilder` rathe than a `MaterialPageRoute`.

```
Navigator.push(context, PageRouteBuilder(opaque: false, pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => DismissableScreen()));
```

[image]